# Java Selenium inconsistancies

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I am trying to figure out how to traverse through a couple screens on a website and retrieve data using Selenium (first attempt at using this) and at the moment the firefox webdriver.  I am getting itermittent results with it working sometimes and not others.  I started by using the Selenium IDE in firefox and recording what I am trying to do.  I used this as my basis for my java program below.  On export I got this error: "// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | ghinwidget_iFrame_0 | ]]".  I transformed that into: "driver.switchTo().frame("ghinwidget_iFrame_0");".  That failed and somehow I got "driver.switchTo().frame("ghinwidget_iFrame_3");" to work, but now cannot figure out where I got ..._iFrame_3.  This all now works most of the time, but frequently fails on "waitOnID("ghinwidget_iFrame_3", 20);" on timeout.  If I switch to firefox, it is exactly where I expect to be waiting for GHIN Number: input.

```
My sequence:
    Go to www.ghin.com
    Click on Handicap Lookup
        This is where my java program will fail if it is going to
    Enter GHIN number: 1234567
    Press "Lookup" button

    Data I am expecting and get most of the time.
```

Can anyone explain my inconsistencies?

```
package org.ghinlookup;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class GHINLookup
{
        private static WebDriver driver;
        private static String baseUrl;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", 
                "/Users/myuser/Desktop/Desktop Archive/Crashplan/Gecko/geckodriver");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://www.ghin.com/";

        driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
        System.out.println("1Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("b")).click();
        waitOnID("ghinwidget_iFrame_3", 20);

        System.out.println("2Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | ghinwidget_iFrame_0 | ]]
        driver.switchTo().frame("ghinwidget_iFrame_3");
        waitOnID("ctl00_bodyMP_tcLookupModes_tpSingle_tbGHIN", 2);

        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_bodyMP_tcLookupModes_tpSingle_tbGHIN")).clear();
        waitOnID("ctl00_bodyMP_tcLookupModes_tpSingle_tbGHIN", 2);

        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_bodyMP_tcLookupModes_tpSingle_tbGHIN")).sendKeys("1234567");
        waitOnID("ctl00_bodyMP_tcLookupModes_tpSingle_btnSubmit1", 2);

        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_bodyMP_tcLookupModes_tpSingle_btnSubmit1")).click();
        waitOnID("__tab_ctl00_bodyMP_tcItems_tpMostRecent", 2);

        driver.findElement(By.id("__tab_ctl00_bodyMP_tcItems_tpMostRecent")).click();

//        driver.switchTo().frame("ghinwidget_iFrame_0");
//        waitOnID("ctl00_bodyMP_tcItems_tpMostRecent_slMostRecent_grdScores", 20);

        WebElement recentScores = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_bodyMP_tcItems_tpMostRecent_slMostRecent_grdScores"));
        String text = recentScores.getText();

        System.out.println(text);

        driver.quit();
    }

    private static void waitOnID(String elementID, int secs)
    {
        System.out.println("Waiting on : " + elementID);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, secs);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(elementID)));
        System.out.println("Got : " + elementID);
    }

    private static void sleepFor(int secs)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * secs);                         // Wait 2 seconds
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(GHINLookup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in method waitOnID switch expectedcondition to visibilityOf() in place of presence.....

Comment: Although this appears to work more often, I still get "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: ghinwidget_iFrame_3 (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)."  It seems to me ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated is superset of ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated.  The latter gets only visible while the former gets both visible and invisible?

Comment: Presence checks if element is available in the dom but not whether visible or hidden. Other one checks both